# Many to many with outer join and dapper

Tags: c#, mysql, many-to-many, dapper, outer-join

I have three tables

- Users `(id, firstname, lastname)`
- Modules `(id, name)`
- Users_modules `(id, u_id, m_id, secret, token)` (many-to-many. Represents modules that are authorized for users)

What would be the query to get the following data back for a specific user:

- User `(id, firstname, lastname)`
- Authorized modules `(id, 1 as isAuthorized)` from users_modules
- Unauthorized modules `(id, 0 as isAuthorized)` outer join with modules

for the sake of me, couldn't figure this out. 
This is my try:

```
Select u.firstName, u.lastName, u.id, m.id,m.name
From modules m
Left Outer Join users_modules uc On uc.m_id = m.id
Left Outer Join users u On
    u.id = uc.u_id And
    u.id = 120
```

Then I want to map the results back to my `User` class using dapper so that `user` object will have all `modules` authorized and unauthorized in `Modules` list property

```
public class User
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public List<Module> Modules{ get; set; }

        public User()
        {
            Modules= new List<Module>();
        }
    }

[Table("modules")]
    public class Module
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string AuthorizationBaseUri { get; set; }
        public bool IsAuthorized { get; set; }
        public string LoginUrl { get; set; }

        public Module()
        {
            LoginUrl = string.Empty;
            AuthorizationBaseUri = string.Empty;
            IsAuthorized = false;
        }
    }
```

I had to get the authorized modules for a user first (using dapper multiple mapping), then get all modules, and then finally do the subtraction manually at my business layer. I know there is a smarter way to do it, yet to find out.

Comment: what is the fields you need in your users_modules table?

Comment: @reds a calculated field (per module) that returns 1 (true) if user has been mapped to a module and 0 (false) if user does not have mapping to a module. Does that answer your question?

Comment: got  a problem of your table given from above.. you are using users_modules but not using any fields of it.

Comment: what is the related fields of that table to another table? or what fields you need on that table?

Comment: much better to add your desired result here.

Answer (score 0):

You have almost solved the problem, but you missed one thing, if a user doesnt have a connection to a module, the left outer join with the left side being the "modules" wont result in anything. To solve this problem you only have to change the side of the "left" side of the left outer join or switch it for a right outer join:

```
Select u.firstName, u.lastName, u.id, m.id,m.name
From users u
Left Outer Join users_modules uc On uc.u_id = u.id
Left Outer Join modules m On m.id = uc.m_id
where u.id = 120 and uc.u_id = 120
```

Comment: This returns the first user that has connection to a module if the passed u.id does not exist in the mapping table. Tried it with different scenarios, it does not give me exactly what i am looking for.

Comment: Sorry @RamiShareef you are right, i have edited, could you please try again and see if this works now?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select u_m.id,firstname,lastname,m_id, secret, token,name from
(select u.id,firstname,lastname,m_id, secret, token from
(select id, firstname, lastname from users where id = 120) as u
left join
(select id, u_id, m_id, secret, token from users_modules) as um
on u.id = um.u_id) as u_m
left join
(select id,name from modules)  as m
on m.id = u_m.m_id
```